# How to use jQuery to transfer values in input field to phpMailer file

Tags: php, jquery, html

So I have a html form with basic text input fields. When the button is pressed, jquery creates an object and then sends this object to the phpMailer file. How would I go about this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

Use an post request for this:

```
var formData = $( "#myForm" ).serialize(); //for example

$.post( "{pathToYourMailerPHP}", formData, function( res ) {

//this function will be called when php response successfull

} );
```